# Losing data/files after app closes Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am developing a crossplatform app with Xamarin and got stuck with this problem.
Every time I launch my app, all the data I had saved before is lost.
To give more details, I am using SQLite to persist some information and even storing some image files in the app's default directory. When I am running the app, I can persist everything successfully and even retrieve the data that I just persisted. But if I close the app and relaunch it, all the information and the files are gone.
To get the directory, I am using the code below, which is suggested in the Xamarin tutorials.

```cs
string documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal); 
var path = Path.Combine(documentsPath, sqlite Filename);
```

At the moment I am focusing my tests on the Android, so I don't know if it happens on the other platforms. I am also using the Trial License, maybe it is some limitation related to it.
I am also using Visual Studio 2013.

Does anyone have an ideia about it?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "launching app" you mean starting new debuggin session from VS just go to Tools - Options - Xamarin - Android Settings and tick "Preserve application data/cache on device between deploys" option.

Xamarin Studio should have same option somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing the app on VS and deploying it to a test device the data may not persist as I explain below.

What I discovered is that when I close the app on the phone (at least on the iPhone 12 I am testing with) and then reopen the app by launching it again on the phone, the data persists.

Now, if I then relaunch the app from VS the data still persists.  Good.

However, when I make a change to the app I find that I need to eliminate the app on the phone for VS to install the new app.  It is annoying, but I have gotten used to deleting the app on the phone before launching it again in VS.  In this case the data does not persist.  Removing the app on the phone removes its data as well.  This all makes perfect sense but it was confusing when I first started testing my app with sqlite.